# Extracting multiple cells in multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, I am trying to figure how to pull data from multiple cells for every row where one column meets certain criteria. For example, for every row where column A ="XYZ" how would I have the data in columns B, C, and D auto-populate in another spreadsheet.

Can't figure it out. thanks

Comment: Try to provide a sample abut your problem, this will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy to do, but I think highlights an important issue in solving difficulties in setting up spreadsheets.

In a programming scenario, one writes code that DOES something, so one would phrase this problem just like in the post. "How do I look at this, then push Data X to some other place?" and is appropriate since one's program is going to do the look-see, then take Data X from where it's found and populate some other place with it.

With Excel formulas though, one does not take something from somewhere to put somewhere else, one goes to the somewhere else and writes formulas that go get the data and put it where they are. So in a way, it's like instead of collecting your child, driving him to school, and depositing him there, it is more along the lines of the school comes and gets your child, drives him to school, and deposits him there. A huge difference.

So, to solve this, instead of starting where the data is and writing VBA (which is a programming language so you'd be programming, not using Excel's other forte, formulas), go to the place it needs to end up and think of it from the viewpoint of "How do I get the data here?" and not "How do I take it and place it here?"

Say the cell to look at is A1 and the data is in B1, C1, and D1, and your goal is for it to be in cells X1, Y1, and Z1. (Copies of it. So in both places.) You just need to write a formula like the following to compare A1 to the criteria and if it succeeds, copy the data to the three cells:

```
=IF( Compare_A1_to_the_Criteria, B1, "")   in cell X1
=IF( Compare_A1_to_the_Criteria, C1, "")   in cell Y1
=IF( Compare_A1_to_the_Criteria, D1, "")   in cell Z1
```

Viewpoint is the key to understanding a lot more in Excel. A huge area is "Just how is MS looking at this function 'cause I don't get their help topic's material AT ALL." Realize one day they have an exceedingly odd point of origin, and it all makes sense. (Not why they looked at it that way, nor why they didn't explain that choice, nor why they chose a non-logical-to-spreadsheets point of origin, but at least the subject matter is now making sense.) ANY TIME in Excel you don't see things working the way the documentation "says they do", it is a viewpoint issue.

And how to structure things, like here, is a similar thing. Any time it just seems it can't possibly do a simple thing you're sure you've seen in other spreadsheets, it's because you are looking at it from the wrong end of the stick. Switch ends and it will usually be incredibly easy, like this problem.

Comment: thank you that is very helpful and will definitely help in the future. For this situation, the formula you suggested, "=IF( Compare_A1_to_the_Criteria, B1, "")   in cell X1" can that be applied to an entire column, so it pulls the data from any row that meets the criteria?